# Query Like no SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Estou tentando fazer uma query like no sqlite.

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT nome FROM Armas WHERE nome LIKE ?", new String[]{name});
```

Essa String eu passo assim:

```
 data = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
        final List<String> getFinalResult = databaseAccess.pesquisaArmas("%" + data + "%");
```

Mas não tá retornando com o like, tá retornando todos os registros. 
Qual a maneira de se fazer pra retornar só o que foi passado na variável data?

Comment: Tente colocar aspas simples  `" '%" + data + "%' "`

Comment: não deu certo, não retornou nenhum registro

Comment: Mas dentro de name tem alguma coisa escrito?! Porque a lógica é essa mesmo, colocar entre aspas ou simples, ou colocar `"\"%" + data + "%\""`

Comment: coloquei um toast e tá passando sim. A variável tá recebendo um texto.

Comment: Cara, tenho quase, digo quase, certeza que o erro é por causa das aspas.

Comment: tirei as aspas, dei um clean build e funcionou =/

Comment: Tirou ou colocou? Agora você confundiu. ehueh

Comment: tirei. Do jeito que eu tinha feito só foi dar um clean build e funcionou